# Exception on getting location in UWP

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, permissions, xamarin.essentials

I have a `Xamarin.Forms application`, which uses `Xamarin.Essentials` and `Plugin.Permissions` plugin.

```
permissionStatus = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Location);
```

In `UWP`, It throws an Exception

> "Server execution failed".

Any ideas what can cause it, and how this can be solved?

Comment: ,If I check Location in package.appxmanifest, I use `Geolocation.GetLocationAsync()` I don't find any error, and I can get Latitude and Longitude. So can you provide one demo that can reproduce this issue here?

Comment: @Cherry Bu Hmm, things changed, and I updated my original question.

Comment: ,According to your code, you want to get location permission for your project? if yes, please take a look my reply.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, I guess that you want to request and check location permission, if yes, you can take a look the following code to request location permission.

```
 try
        {
            var status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Location);
            if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                if(await CrossPermissions.Current.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationaleAsync(Permission.Location))
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Need location", "Gunna need that location", "OK");
                }

                var results = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(Permission.Location);
                status = results[Permission.Location];
            }

            if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                var results = await CrossGeolocator.Current.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                LabelGeolocation.Text = "Lat: " + results.Latitude + " Long: " + results.Longitude;
            }
            else if(status != PermissionStatus.Unknown)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Location Denied", "Can not continue, try again.", "OK");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            LabelGeolocation.Text = "Error: " + ex;
        }
```

Please check Location in package.appxmanifest before.

Comment: But I have the problem with the very first statement. You can see that your code does not differ from mine on that line... And I do have the Location checked...

Comment: @David, I don't think so, because the parameter type in CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync() method is Permission, so if you want to get Location permission, it should be Permission.Location. If you want to get location permission, I suggest you can try my code firstly.

Comment: The "permission" that I pass is actually set to Permission.Location. This part of code is just not included in my question.

Comment: @David, now, I am confused about your problem, do you try my code?

Comment: The first line of your code is the same that I have. And that line throws an exception. There is no point to go further, as the execution never passes the FIRST line (CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync).